# Why do we use dx when X is not a function?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, differential, chain-rule

I know what a differential is, to the extent of Riemann sums. But when differentiating a function, say y=f(x), then oftentimes I see dy = f'(x)dx by the chain rule, which makes sense. But X isn't a function, it's the base variable, so how does it's derivative matter? On any case, if X is understood as the axis, wouldn't it's derivative simply be 1?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: $dx$ is not a derivative, it is a differential. By your own admission, $dx=(x)'dx$ "makes sense".

Comment: $dy=f'(x)dx$ is simply $dy/dx=f'(x)$ and $y=f(x)$ depends on $x$.

Comment: When calculus is developed rigorously, in real analysis courses that use textbooks such as Understanding Analysis by Abbot, typically “differentials” like $dx$ and $dy$ are avoided entirely. So while $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is the derivative of $y$, there is no such thing as $dx$ by itself or $dy$ by itself. In this approach, we would simply avoid writing things like $dy = f’(x) dx$. (Later, if we develop the language of differential forms, we can say such things. But this is unnecessary for understanding calculus.)

Comment: That said, “infinitesimal intuition” is very powerful, even if it’s not totally rigorous. I often think of $\Delta x$ as a tiny change in the value of $x$, and $\Delta f$ is the corresponding change in the value of $f$. Then $f’(x) \approx \frac{\Delta f}{\Delta x}$. This helps to explain why $\frac{df}{dx}$ is a popular notation for the derivative of $f$.

Comment: If $x:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is the identity function and $df=f'$ denotes the derivative everything is also formally correct if you read the *evaluation* $y=f(x)$ as a composion $y=f\circ x=f$. Then $dy=f'=f'(x)=f'(x) dx$ because $dx$ is constant function with value $1$.

Comment: @Jochen I think this is what I was looking for. Care to explain what the symbol "∘" stands for? Also, isn't the identity function one so that $f(X)=X$?

Comment: $\circ$ is the compostion of functions. Sure, the identity $x:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ satisfies $f=f\circ x=f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's derivative is indeed 1.

Suppose you have $y=f(g(x))$.

where $f,\;g$ are differentiable, then by the chain rule:

$df=f'(g(x))g'(x)dx$

In this case:
$g(x)=x, \;x'(x)=1$.